# Special letters on axis, R plot

Tags: r, plot, special-characters

I have a problem with special letters in plots. Here's an example:

```
plot(1:10,1:10, xlab="Idő", ylab=" ")
```

After I export the plot in pdf, which is what i need, the "ő" letter disappears from the text and becomes simply "Ido". How can it be solved?

Thanks!

Comment: Which command do you use to export in pdf... And what is your OS...?

Comment: I simply click Save as, then pdf.

Comment: Click save as in what?

Comment: At file? From the menu bar.

Comment: menu bar of what?...

Comment: No, I think @zapp is using RGui and what he's describing makes sense.

Comment: Ah yes, RGui, sorry, i didn't exaclty get the question. I'm using windows 7.

Comment: @zapp Does the letter appear in the graphics device before you export as PDF? In addition would using `xlab = "Id\U0151"`work as a solution for you?

Comment: Yes, i can see it in the device, it disappears after the exporting. I tried your  @sebastian-c, but it's still missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the default encoding of the pdf device in RGui. You'll have to open and close the device from R:

```
pdf(file="test.pdf", encoding="CP1250")
plot(1:10,1:10, xlab="Id\U0151", ylab=" ")
dev.off()
```